# Can I use this sql statement to search through asp:textbox

Tags: sql, .net-4.0

I have this SQL statement which is working fine, but it doesn't satisfy my needs. It is retrieving all the data from the table which should exactly be the same. I mean the `First name` in the table should be exactly the textbox's text. This is the SQL statement I am using.

```
SELECT        
    CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Mobile
FROM
    Customers
WHERE        
    (FirstName = @FirstName)
```

What I need is something related to `LIKE` condition I guess, which it works like this: there is data in the table "Sample Text" and I write down in the textbox Samp, Sam, Sa, and any text which is the same to the data in the table the data will automatically display. btw I am using Micosoft Visual Studio to help me to build my query using query builder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at least in regards to the query, this is what you need:

```
SELECT        CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Mobile
FROM            Customers
WHERE        FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName
```

You will be sending the temporary first name from your text box to the SQL server and display the results for selection.